# Setting up EclipseFP on Galileo with GHC 6.12

Tags: eclipse, haskell, cabal

I've installed EclipseFP on Eclipse and when it starts it mentions I need to install `buildwrapper` and `scion-browser`. I updated cabal and tried to install each but I get this error from `sudo cabal install buildwrapper`:

```
david@mycomputer:~$ sudo cabal install buildwrapper
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: internal error: could not construct a valid install plan.
The proposed (invalid) plan contained the following problems:
The following packages are involved in a dependency cycle buildwrapper-0.5.2
```

And I get this message from `sudo cabal install scion-browser` saying I need to specify I different base library (related question: how would I tell cabal to use a different base library?)

```
david@mycomputer:~$ sudo cabal install scion-browser
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: cannot configure conduit-0.4.2. It requires base >=4.3 && <5
For the dependency on base >=4.3 && <5 there are these packages: base-4.3.0.0,
base-4.3.1.0, base-4.4.0.0, base-4.4.1.0, base-4.5.0.0 and base-4.5.1.0.
However none of them are available.
base-4.3.0.0 was excluded because unix-2.4.0.0 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.0.0 was excluded because template-haskell-2.4.0.0 requires base
==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.0.0 was excluded because process-1.0.1.2 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.0.0 was excluded because pretty-1.0.1.1 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.0.0 was excluded because old-time-1.0.0.3 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.0.0 was excluded because old-locale-1.0.0.2 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.0.0 was excluded because hpc-0.5.0.4 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.0.0 was excluded because ghc-binary-0.5.0.2 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.0.0 was excluded because filepath-1.1.0.3 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.0.0 was excluded because directory-1.0.1.0 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.0.0 was excluded because containers-0.3.0.0 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.0.0 was excluded because bytestring-0.9.1.5 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.0.0 was excluded because bin-package-db-0.0.0.0 requires base
==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.0.0 was excluded because array-0.3.0.0 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.0.0 was excluded because Cabal-1.8.0.2 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.0.0 was excluded because ghc-6.12.1 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.0.0 was excluded because of the top level dependency base -any
base-4.3.1.0 was excluded because unix-2.4.0.0 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.1.0 was excluded because template-haskell-2.4.0.0 requires base
==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.1.0 was excluded because process-1.0.1.2 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.1.0 was excluded because pretty-1.0.1.1 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.1.0 was excluded because old-time-1.0.0.3 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.1.0 was excluded because old-locale-1.0.0.2 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.1.0 was excluded because hpc-0.5.0.4 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.1.0 was excluded because ghc-binary-0.5.0.2 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.1.0 was excluded because filepath-1.1.0.3 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.1.0 was excluded because directory-1.0.1.0 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.1.0 was excluded because containers-0.3.0.0 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.1.0 was excluded because bytestring-0.9.1.5 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.1.0 was excluded because bin-package-db-0.0.0.0 requires base
==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.1.0 was excluded because array-0.3.0.0 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.1.0 was excluded because Cabal-1.8.0.2 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.1.0 was excluded because ghc-6.12.1 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.3.1.0 was excluded because of the top level dependency base -any
base-4.4.0.0 was excluded because uniplate-1.6.7 requires base >=4 && <4.4
base-4.4.0.0 was excluded because unix-2.4.0.0 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.0.0 was excluded because template-haskell-2.4.0.0 requires base
==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.0.0 was excluded because process-1.0.1.2 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.0.0 was excluded because pretty-1.0.1.1 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.0.0 was excluded because old-time-1.0.0.3 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.0.0 was excluded because old-locale-1.0.0.2 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.0.0 was excluded because hpc-0.5.0.4 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.0.0 was excluded because ghc-binary-0.5.0.2 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.0.0 was excluded because filepath-1.1.0.3 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.0.0 was excluded because directory-1.0.1.0 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.0.0 was excluded because containers-0.3.0.0 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.0.0 was excluded because bytestring-0.9.1.5 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.0.0 was excluded because bin-package-db-0.0.0.0 requires base
==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.0.0 was excluded because array-0.3.0.0 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.0.0 was excluded because Cabal-1.8.0.2 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.0.0 was excluded because ghc-6.12.1 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.0.0 was excluded because of the top level dependency base -any
base-4.4.1.0 was excluded because uniplate-1.6.7 requires base >=4 && <4.4
base-4.4.1.0 was excluded because unix-2.4.0.0 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.1.0 was excluded because template-haskell-2.4.0.0 requires base
==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.1.0 was excluded because process-1.0.1.2 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.1.0 was excluded because pretty-1.0.1.1 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.1.0 was excluded because old-time-1.0.0.3 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.1.0 was excluded because old-locale-1.0.0.2 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.1.0 was excluded because hpc-0.5.0.4 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.1.0 was excluded because ghc-binary-0.5.0.2 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.1.0 was excluded because filepath-1.1.0.3 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.1.0 was excluded because directory-1.0.1.0 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.1.0 was excluded because containers-0.3.0.0 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.1.0 was excluded because bytestring-0.9.1.5 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.1.0 was excluded because bin-package-db-0.0.0.0 requires base
==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.1.0 was excluded because array-0.3.0.0 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.1.0 was excluded because Cabal-1.8.0.2 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.1.0 was excluded because ghc-6.12.1 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.4.1.0 was excluded because of the top level dependency base -any
base-4.5.0.0 was excluded because uniplate-1.6.7 requires base >=4 && <4.4
base-4.5.0.0 was excluded because unix-2.4.0.0 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.0.0 was excluded because template-haskell-2.4.0.0 requires base
==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.0.0 was excluded because process-1.0.1.2 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.0.0 was excluded because pretty-1.0.1.1 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.0.0 was excluded because old-time-1.0.0.3 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.0.0 was excluded because old-locale-1.0.0.2 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.0.0 was excluded because hpc-0.5.0.4 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.0.0 was excluded because ghc-binary-0.5.0.2 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.0.0 was excluded because filepath-1.1.0.3 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.0.0 was excluded because directory-1.0.1.0 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.0.0 was excluded because containers-0.3.0.0 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.0.0 was excluded because bytestring-0.9.1.5 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.0.0 was excluded because bin-package-db-0.0.0.0 requires base
==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.0.0 was excluded because array-0.3.0.0 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.0.0 was excluded because Cabal-1.8.0.2 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.0.0 was excluded because ghc-6.12.1 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.0.0 was excluded because of the top level dependency base -any
base-4.5.1.0 was excluded because uniplate-1.6.7 requires base >=4 && <4.4
base-4.5.1.0 was excluded because unix-2.4.0.0 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.1.0 was excluded because template-haskell-2.4.0.0 requires base
==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.1.0 was excluded because process-1.0.1.2 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.1.0 was excluded because pretty-1.0.1.1 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.1.0 was excluded because old-time-1.0.0.3 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.1.0 was excluded because old-locale-1.0.0.2 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.1.0 was excluded because hpc-0.5.0.4 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.1.0 was excluded because ghc-binary-0.5.0.2 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.1.0 was excluded because filepath-1.1.0.3 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.1.0 was excluded because directory-1.0.1.0 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.1.0 was excluded because containers-0.3.0.0 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.1.0 was excluded because bytestring-0.9.1.5 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.1.0 was excluded because bin-package-db-0.0.0.0 requires base
==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.1.0 was excluded because array-0.3.0.0 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.1.0 was excluded because Cabal-1.8.0.2 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.1.0 was excluded because ghc-6.12.1 requires base ==4.2.0.0
base-4.5.1.0 was excluded because of the top level dependency base -any
```

Does anyone know how to get these library to install so that I can use EclipseFP? On the popup when Eclipse starts it has an install for these libraries but pressing it doesn't do anything.

Comment: This (probably) isn't related to your problem, but unless you know what you are doing, you should run `cabal install` as user, not root.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a newer base by upgrading GHC. I recommend this: GHC 6.12 is now 2.5 years old, and a lot happens in that time.

At a guess, the cyclic dependency comes from using an old version of cabal(-install). Newer versions of cabal allow a single package to provide both a library and an executable (which may depend on the library); to old versions, this probably looks like a single-package cyclic dependency.

Comment: That's probably what's doing it. I've been needing to update my distro to the newer version anyway.